# Cannot compile COLLADA with CMAKE for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, collada

Hi I am trying to build the Collada plugin for the [Mitsuba Renderer](http://www.mitsuba-renderer.org/).

Everytime it gets to the (FindCOLLADA.cmake) file it freeze in CMAKE and does not go forward.
I am able to recreate this on another desktop, but on my laptop .. it runs fine.
So its an odd error since it does not hang on the laptop, but on my 2 desktops it hangs at this stage and does not continue.

If I do not add the COLLADA plugin .. it compiles the project fine.
So I am pretty sure I have it isolated to this.

Putting some STATUS MESSAGES in I can see it hangs on this line:

```
# Locate the actual library
FIND_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG(COLLADA NAMES ${COLLADADOM_NAMES} DEFAULT_SUFFIXES
   PATHS ${Collada_library_paths} ${COLLADA_generic_lib_path})
```

Here is the whole FindCOLLADA.cmake file

```
# - Find COLLADA
# This module searches for the COLLADA library, by default using version 1.4
# of the COLLADA DOM Schema.
# 
# The module defines the following variables:
#  COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIRS - where to find dae.h, etc.
#  COLLADA_LIBRARIES    - the libraries needed to use COLLADA.
#  COLLADA_DEFINITIONS  - preprocessor definitions to use with COLLADA.
#  COLLADA_NAMESPACE    - boolean to indicate whether this version contains the
#                         namespaces and new functions introduced with
#                         COLLADA-DOM 2.4.
# COLLADA_NAMESPACE_141 - boolean to indicate wheter the namespace
#                         ColladaDOM141 is supported.
# COLLADA_NAMESPACE_150 - boolean to indicate wheter the namespace
#                         ColladaDOM150 is supported.
#  COLLADA_FOUND        - if false, do not try to use COLLADA.
#
# Variables used by this module, they can change the default behavior and need
# to be set before calling find_package:
#
#  COLLADADOM_15    - if set to a value which evaluates to true, the module
#                     will look for the COLLADA DOM Scheva version 1.5
#                     components instead of the default (1.4.)
#  COLLADA_ROOT_DIR - The prefered installation prefix for searching for
#                     COLLADA. This corresponds to
#                     ./configure --prefix=$COLLADA_ROOT_DIR
#                     Set if this module has problems finding the proper
#                     COLLADA instalation.
#

# ============================================================================
# Originally created by Robert Osfield. [OpenSceneGraph]
# ============================================================================


# Standarnd issue macros
include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
include (FindPackageMessage)
include (FindReleaseAndDebug)
include (CheckCXXSourceCompiles)

if (COLLADA_15)
  set (COLLADADOM_VERSION    "15")
  set (COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT "1.5")
else()
  set (COLLADADOM_VERSION    "14")
  set (COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT "1.4")
endif()
set(COLLADA_VERSIONS "2.5" 25 "2.4" 24 23 22 21 20 2)

MESSAGE( STATUS "COLLADADOM_VERSION:         " ${COLLADADOM_VERSION} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT:         " ${COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "COLLADA_VERSIONS:         " ${COLLADA_VERSIONS} )

#set (COLLADA_VERSIONS "2.4")
#set (COLLADA_LIBRARY
#  optimized
#  C:/CODE/mitsuba_12/dependencies/lib/x64/collada-dom2.4-dp-vc110-mt.lib
#  debug
#  C:/CODE/mitsuba_12/dependencies/lib/x64/collada-dom2.4-dp-vc110-mt_debug.lib
#  )

# Default search paths
set (COLLADA_generic_include_path
  ~/Library/Frameworks
  /Library/Frameworks
  /opt/local/Library/Frameworks #macports
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/local/include/colladadom
  /usr/include/
  /usr/include/colladadom
  /sw/include # Fink
  /opt/local/include # DarwinPorts
  /opt/csw/include # Blastwave
  /opt/include
  /usr/freeware/include
  #/collada-dom
  #/collada-dom/1.4
  #collada-dom
  #collada-dom/1.4
  #${MTS_DEPS_DIR}/include/collada-dom
  #${MTS_DEPS_DIR}/include/collada-dom/1.4
)
set (COLLADA_generic_lib_path
  #/lib/x64
  #lib/x64
  #${MTS_DEPS_DIR}/lib/x64
)


# Macro to assemble a helper state variable
macro (SET_STATE_VAR varname)
  set (tmp_lst ColladaDOM | ${COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIR} | ${COLLADA_LIBRARY})
  set (${varname} "${tmp_lst}")
  unset (tmp_lst)
endmacro ()

# Macro to search for an include directory
macro (PREFIX_FIND_INCLUDE_DIR prefix includefile libpath_var)
  string (TOUPPER ${prefix}_INCLUDE_DIR tmp_varname)
  find_path(${tmp_varname} ${includefile}
    HINTS ${${libpath_var}}
    PATHS ${COLLADA_generic_include_path}
    PATH_SUFFIXES
      "collada-dom2.4" "collada_dom2.4"
        "include/collada-dom2.4" "include/collada_dom2.4"
      "collada-dom" "collada_dom" "include"
        "include/collada-dom" "include/collada_dom"
  )
  if (${tmp_varname})
    mark_as_advanced (${tmp_varname})
  endif ()
  unset (tmp_varname)
endmacro ()

# Macro to test for namespace support. Factorized just to keep the code cleaner
macro (COLLADA_CHECK_NAMESPACE)

  # COLLADA-DOM 2.4 needs special treatment
  set(_COLLADA_OLD_DEFINITIONS ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS})
  set(_COLLADA_OLD_INCLUDES    ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES})
  set(_COLLADA_OLD_LIBRARIES   ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES})

  # Flags for the test source:
  #  (1 << 0) - COLLADA-DOM 1.4.1
  #  (1 << 1) - COLLADA-DOM 1.5.0
  set(_COLLADA_TEST_SRC "
#define NO_BOOST
#ifdef COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT150
# undef COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT150
#endif
#ifdef COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT141
# undef COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT141
#endif
#ifdef COLLADA_DOM_NAMESPACE
# undef COLLADA_DOM_NAMESPACE
#endif
#ifndef COLLADA_FLAGS
# define COLLADA_FLAGS 0
#endif

#define COLLADA_DOM_NAMESPACE
#if (COLLADA_FLAGS & (1 << 0)) != 0
# define COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT141
#endif
#if (COLLADA_FLAGS & (1 << 1)) != 0
# define COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT150
#endif
#include <dae.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DAE dae;
    int result = 0;
#ifdef COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT141
    ColladaDOM141::domCOLLADA* root1 = dae.getRoot141(argv[0]);
    result += ((int*)root1)[argc];
#endif
#ifdef COLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT150
    ColladaDOM150::domCOLLADA* root2 = dae.getRoot150(argv[0]);
    result += ((int*)root2)[argc];
#endif
    return result;
}
  ")

  # Run the tests
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES  ${COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES ${COLLADA_LIBRARIES})

  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS "-DCOLLADA_FLAGS=3")
  CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES("${_COLLADA_TEST_SRC}" HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141_150)
  # Perhaps it was compiled with only one of the namespaces
  if (NOT HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141_150)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS "-DCOLLADA_FLAGS=1")
    CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES("${_COLLADA_TEST_SRC}" HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS "-DCOLLADA_FLAGS=2")
    CHECK_CXX_SOURCE_COMPILES("${_COLLADA_TEST_SRC}" HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_150)
  endif()

  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS ${_COLLADA_OLD_DEFINITIONS})
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES    ${_COLLADA_OLD_INCLUDES})
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES   ${_COLLADA_OLD_LIBRARIES})
  unset(_COLLADA_TEST_SRC)
  unset(_COLLADA_OLD_INCLUDES)
  unset(_COLLADA_OLD_LIBRARIES)
endmacro()


# Encode the current state of the external variables into a string
SET_STATE_VAR (COLLADA_CURRENT_STATE)

# If the state has changed, clear the cached variables
if (COLLADA_CACHED_STATE AND
    NOT COLLADA_CACHED_STATE STREQUAL COLLADA_CURRENT_STATE)
  foreach (libvar ${COLLADA_CACHED_VARS})
    unset (${libvar} CACHE)
  endforeach ()
endif ()


# Where to look for the libraries
if(APPLE)
  set(COLLADA_BUILDNAME "mac")
elseif(MINGW)
  set(COLLADA_BUILDNAME "mingw")
elseif(MSVC)
  math(EXPR COLLADA_BUILDNAME "(${MSVC_VERSION} - 600) / 100")
  set(COLLADA_BUILDNAME "vc${COLLADA_BUILDNAME}")
endif()

set(Collada_library_paths
  ${COLLADA_ROOT_DIR}
  ${COLLADA_ROOT_DIR}/lib
  ${COLLADA_ROOT_DIR}/lib/x64
  ${MTS_DEPS_DIR}/lib/x64
  ${COLLADA_ROOT_DIR}/build/${COLLADA_BUILDNAME}-${COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT}
  /build/${COLLADA_BUILDNAME}-${COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT}
)

# Construct the possible names for the DOM library
set(COLLADADOM_NAMES
  collada-dom
  collada${COLLADADOM_VERSION}dom
  Collada${COLLADADOM_VERSION}Dom
)
if (MSVC)
  set(COLLADADOM_NAMES ${COLLADADOM_NAMES}
    libcollada-dom
    libCollada${COLLADADOM_VERSION}Dom
    libcollada${COLLADADOM_VERSION}dom
  )
endif()

# Version suffixes for MSVC
if (MSVC)
  math(EXPR VC_SUFFIX_A "(${MSVC_VERSION} - 600) / 10")
  math(EXPR VC_SUFFIX_B "${VC_SUFFIX_A} / 10")
  set(VC_SUFFIXES "vc${VC_SUFFIX_A}-mt" "vc${VC_SUFFIX_B}-mt"
                  "vc${VC_SUFFIX_A}"    "vc${VC_SUFFIX_B}")
  unset(VC_SUFFIX_A)
  unset(VC_SUFFIX_B)
endif()
set(COLLADADOM_NAMES_BASE ${COLLADADOM_NAMES})
foreach(name ${COLLADADOM_NAMES_BASE})
  foreach(version ${COLLADA_VERSIONS})
    list(APPEND COLLADADOM_NAMES "${name}${version}-dp" "${name}${version}")
    if(MSVC)
      foreach(vc_suffix ${VC_SUFFIXES})
        list(APPEND COLLADADOM_NAMES "${name}${version}-dp-${vc_suffix}"
          "${name}${version}-${vc_suffix}")
      endforeach()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endforeach()
unset(COLLADADOM_NAMES_BASE)
unset(VC_SUFFIXES)

# Locate the header files
PREFIX_FIND_INCLUDE_DIR (COLLADA dae.h COLLADA_ROOT_DIR)


MESSAGE( STATUS "COLLADA_ROOT_DIR:         " ${COLLADA_ROOT_DIR} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "COLLADA_generic_lib_path:         " ${COLLADA_generic_lib_path} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "Collada_library_paths:         " ${Collada_library_paths} )
MESSAGE( STATUS "COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIRS:         " ${COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIRS} )







# Locate the actual library
FIND_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG(COLLADA NAMES ${COLLADADOM_NAMES} DEFAULT_SUFFIXES
  PATHS ${Collada_library_paths} ${COLLADA_generic_lib_path})

# Create the list of variables that might need to be cleared.
# The libraries and include path are not cleared since they might be manually
# set by the user. Besides they will be processed again if the user deletes
# them from the CMake cache. Only the internal cache variables need to be
# specifically cleared so that the tests run again.
set (COLLADA_CACHED_VARS
  HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141_150 HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141 HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_150
  CACHE INTERNAL "Variables set by FindCOLLADA.cmake" FORCE)

# Store the current state so that variables might be cleared if required
set (COLLADA_CACHED_STATE ${COLLADA_CURRENT_STATE}
  CACHE INTERNAL "State last seen by FindCOLLADA.cmake" FORCE)

# Use the standard function to handle COLLADA_FOUND
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS (COLLADA DEFAULT_MSG
  COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIR COLLADA_LIBRARY)

# Set the uncached variables for the appropriate version
if (COLLADA_FOUND)
  set(COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIRS
    ${COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${COLLADA_INCLUDE_DIR}/${COLLADADOM_VERSION_PT})
  set(COLLADA_LIBRARIES ${COLLADA_LIBRARY})

  # Check if this version of COLLADA-DOM contains namespaces introduced in v2.4
  COLLADA_CHECK_NAMESPACE()

  # Set the results and definitions
  if (HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141_150 OR HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141 OR HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_150)
    set(COLLADA_NAMESPACE ON)
    # TODO Check if double support was actually enabled
    set(COLLADA_DEFINITIONS "-DCOLLADA_DOM_NAMESPACE -DCOLLADA_DOM_DAEFLOAT_IS64")
    if (HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141_150 OR HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141)
      set(COLLADA_NAMESPACE_141 ON)
      set(COLLADA_DEFINITIONS "${COLLADA_DEFINITIONS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT141")
    endif()
    if (HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_141_150 OR HAVE_COLLADA_DOM_150)
      set(COLLADA_NAMESPACE_150 ON)
      set(COLLADA_DEFINITIONS "${COLLADA_DEFINITIONS} -DCOLLADA_DOM_SUPPORT150")
    endif()
  else()
    set(COLLADA_NAMESPACE OFF)
    set(COLLADA_NAMESPACE_141 OFF)
    set(COLLADA_NAMESPACE_150 OFF)
    set(COLLADA_DEFINITIONS "")
  endif()
endif()
```

Comment: `FIND_RELEASE_AND_DEBUG` isn't built into CMake and appears to be coming from here: `include (FindReleaseAndDebug)` at the top of your `FindCOLLADA.cmake` file.  My CMake 2.8.9 installation doesn't have this module.  Have you tried `cmake --help-module FindReleaseAndDebug` to see if there is any module documentation that might give you a hint?